# Testing interaction with SpeechRecognizer using Espresso-Intents

Tags: android, android-intent, speech-recognition, android-testing, android-espresso

I am adding instrumentation testing to an application. I want to test an interaction around speech recognition:

- the user clicks on a button (`R.id.buttonVoice`), displaying a `DialogFragment` for speech recognition
- the `SpeechRecognizer` kicks-in, listening to user input
- partial results are displayed in the dialog (not testing this for now)
- once complete, the dialog is closed and the recognized speech is displayed in the activity's `TextView` (`R.id.results`)

Instrumentation testing with [Espresso-Intents](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents) sounds like a good way to make sure my test does not rely on the system's `SpeechRecognizer`.

Here is my test that plays the same interaction with an [`intended()` stubbed intent](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents#stubbing):

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MainActivityWithPermissionTest {

    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule intentsTestRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void clickInput_sendsSpeakIntentAndDisplaysResults() {
        // stub intent returning recognition results
        intending(hasAction(equalTo(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)))
                .respondWith(new ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtra(
                        SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION, new String[]{"I am uttering."})));

        // when clicking on the buttonVoice, thus opening the dialog and starting the speechRecognizer
        onView(withId(R.id.buttonVoice))
                .perform(click());

        // expect the recognition results to be displayed
        onView(withId(R.id.results))
                .check(matches(withText("I am uttering.")));
    }
}
```

This test however fails with error `'with text: is "I am uttering."' doesn't match the selected view.`

Indeed, when I look at the instrumentation happening on the device, I see the **real `SpeechRecognizer` is triggered** (and fails as it's running on the emulator). So it seems my intent stub doesn't work.

#### Why can't I stub the `RecognizerIntent`? Is there another way to test interaction with `SpeechRecognizer` without having your test rely on real speech recognition?